# Boto3/S3/Django: Avoid blocking the event loop while file hash being calculated

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, gunicorn, gevent

From a gunicorn+gevent worker, making (multipart) uploads to S3 via [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), how can I make sure that during the calculation of the hash of file/part contents, the event loop is not blocked?

Looking in the [source for django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/f0094631e509ab0cddc1a9ababcd27210a078db5/storages/backends/s3boto3.py), there doesn't really seem to be any scope for passing in the md5(/another hash), and in the [source for botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1ae092ed95b39c3336ba48c5cbd71b7c37924d05/botocore/handlers.py#L200) there doesn't seem to be scope for yielding the event loop while the hash is being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [PR for django-storages that calculates the MD5 hash as data received by the application](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/pull/672).

In summary, this changes `S3Boto3StorageFile` so on init and new part

```
self._file_md5 = hashlib.md5()
```

and then on receive of `content_bytes`

```
self._file_md5.update(content_bytes)
```

and then when each part is uploaded, the `ContentMD5` parameter is passed to the part upload function

```
ContentMD5=base64.b64encode(self._file_md5.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```